If $f_n\xrightarrow{L^3}f$ and $f_n,f\in L^3$, does it follow that $\int_X f_n^3\to \int_X f^3$?
If $f_n\xrightarrow{L^3}f$ and $f_n,f\in L^3$, does it follow that $\int_X f_n^3\to \int_X f^3$?
I know this statement is true when the measure space is finite. But does it hold in general measure space?
Here is my attempt:
Since $f_n\xrightarrow{L^3}f$, $\|f_n-f\|_3\to 0$. It follows that $\|f_n\|_3\to \|f\|_3$ by the triangle inequality of the $L^3$ norm. Thus, $\|f_n\|_3^3\to \|f\|_3^3$, that is, $\int_X |f_n|^3\to \int_X |f|^3$.
Moreover, $f_n\to f$ in measure. If the measure space is finite, we have $f_n^3\to f^3$ in measure and $|f_n|^3\to |f|^3$ in measure. By the generalized DCT of convergence in measure, it follows that $\int_X f_n^3\to \int_X f^3$.
However, in the general measure space, $f_n\to f$ in measure does not imply $f_n^3\to f^3$ in measure. So, I would like to know whether this statement still holds in the space with infinite measure.
Thanks in advance!

Assume $\|f_n-f\|_3\to 0.$ We have $$\left |\int\limits_X  f_n(x)^3\,d\mu(x)- \int\limits_Xf(x)^3\,d\mu(x)\right |\\ \le\int\limits_X  |f_n(x)^3-f(x)^3|\,d\mu(x) \\ = \int\limits_X | f_n(x)-f(x)|\,[|f_n(x)|^2+|f_n(x)|\,|f(x)|+|f(x)|^2]\,d\mu(x)\\ \le { 3\over 2}\int\limits_X | f_n(x)-f(x)|\,[|f_n(x)|^2+|f(x)|^2]\,d\mu(x)\\ \le {3\over 2}\|f_n-f\|_3\|f_n\|_3^2  +{3\over 2}\|f_n-f\|_3\|f\|_3^2\to 0$$
In the last step we have applied the Hölder inequality with $p=3$ and $q=3/2.$

Thank you very much! Moreover, I noticed that the proof used the factorization of $|f_n^3-f^3|$. I would like to know, for any $1\leq p<\infty$, if both $f_n^p$ and $f^p$ are well-defined, does it still hold that $\int_X f_n^p\to \int_X f^p$? It seems that when $p$ is not an integer, the factorization might not hold.

Thanks for accepting. For general $p$ we may use the mean value theorem $$|a^p-b^p|=p|a-b||\xi|^{p-1}$$ for some $\xi$ in the segment between $a$ and $b.$ Then $|\xi|\le |a|+|b|.$
